# AngularFire, extended $firebaseArray save errors with 'Invalid key $id (cannot contain .$[]#)'

Tags: firebase, angularfire

When extending $firebaseArray I get the error 'invalid key $id (cannot contain .$[]#)'

The issue is with the $id property on the book object.  When calling $save on the array and passing the modified book in, the factory doesn't recognize $id as the id field like it normally would prior to extending.

Html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in bookList"> <a href="#" ng-click="loadBook(book)">{{book.$id}}: {{book.date|date:"medium"}}</a> 
        <button ng-click="setDate(book)">set date</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<pre>{{book|json}}</pre>
```

Javascript

```
// reference to our Firebase instance
var fb = new Firebase('YourUrl');

function Book(snap) {
    // records in synchronized arrays must have a $id property
    this.$id = snap.key();
    this.update(snap);
}

Book.prototype.update = function (snap) {
    angular.extend(this, snap.val());
    // convert json dates to Date objects
    this.date = new Date(this.date||0);
    this.$priority = snap.getPriority();
};

Book.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return angular.extend({}, this, {
        // revert Date objects to json data
        date: this.date.getTime()
    });
};

var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, bookFactory) {    
    // create a synchronized array with a customized version 
    // of $FirebaseArray

    $scope.bookList = new bookFactory(fb);


    // loads a single record for display
    $scope.book = "Click on a book id";
    $scope.loadBook = function (book) {
        $scope.book = book;
    };

    // changes the date on a book record, note that we're working
    // with Date objects here
    $scope.setDate = function(book) {
        book.date = new Date();
        $scope.bookList.$save(book);
    };
});

app.factory('bookFactory', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseUtils) {
    return $firebaseArray.$extend({
        // override $$added to return a Book object
        $$added: function (snap, prevChild) {
            return new Book(snap);
        },

        // override $$updated to update the book object
        $$updated: function (snap) {
          var rec = this.$getRecord(snap.name());
          if(angular.isObject(rec) ) {
            book.update(snap);
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Made a fiddle showing the error, just press 'Set Date' on any of the books.
https://jsfiddle.net/jensenben/h98mjsoz/

This can be remedied if make the book object use id instead of $id and add a $$getKey method to the $extend call to tell it what field has the id in it, but I'd prefer to stick with the traditional $id field that I use when not extending a $firebaseArray.

```
function Book(snap) {
    // records in synchronized arrays must have a $id property
    this.id = snap.key();
    this.update(snap);
}

return $firebaseArray.$extend({
    $$getKey: function(rec) {
        return rec.id;
    },
...
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, noticed i messed the link up but you were faster

Comment: You need to use angular.toJSON() or $firebaseUtils.toJSON() instead of angular.extend(). Angular.extend() will not remove meta data, like $id, before saving.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit much going on, so I'm not sure if this is your problem. But to get rid of the error, convert the `$firebaseObject()` to a regular JSON object when saving:

```
$scope.setDate = function(book) {
    book.date = new Date();
    $scope.bookList.$save(book.toJSON());
};
```

Note that the CSS and most of the JavaScript code are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, first time posting...  I removed some things to clear up a bit.  it was a fork of Kato Richardsons example of extending firebaseArray to deal with UTC dates.

https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/F4Xxa/

Comment: adding toJSON() does stop the error, but the record is never saved to the firebase database.  Run the fiddle in two separate tabs, you'll see each update when the other starts running and resets the data.  But when you set the date, it doesn't save.

Comment: Added an error handle to the save, toJSON results in 'Invalid record; could determine key for [object Object]'

Comment: The OPs toJson() method doesn't actually convert the object to a json format. It calls angular.extend(), which doesn't output valid json.

Comment: Kato, I modeled it from an old fiddle of yours.. https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/F4Xxa/, I'm new to firebase and i'm trying to store UTC date values in firebase... I just can't get this to save.  I've tried a variety of things but haven't figured it out yet.